# how to get server time on a WPF browser Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, xbap

I have a Wpf Browser application coded in C#, the problem is that Date.Time.Now returns the time on the client pc, and is unreliable, how can a obtain the time from my application server or my MSSQL server?

Comment: why don't you get the server datetime on a query and show it on the client?

Comment: What are you getting that makes the server time different than the client time.. also where is the Server physically residing in regards to the Client..?\

Comment: What do you need the server's time for? This is kind of a red flag that you are trying to do something client side that should be done on the server.

Comment: @DJKRAZE some of the clients have the wrong time configured, the server is in Florida and the clients are all over latin america.

Comment: @user1134704 - "different" doesn't mean wrong.  What exactly are you using this for?  Tim is right that is a big red flag

Comment: I left you some sql code you may also want to look at the Universal Time using C#

Comment: @TimB in Xbap apps, the line between server and browser is blurred. It is almost like a winforms app, but it is served to the client's browser.

Comment: @RobertLevy the thing is that there is no way for me to be sure that the clients hay the time on their systems correctly configured, and the data represents bank transfers, so a correct time is crucial.

Comment: if accuracy is important, the server needs to assign a time to the transfer at the time the data is submitted to the server.  you don't need the client to ask the server what the time is so that the client can then pass that back that information back to the server.  too many opportunities for things to go wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting the Servers Current TimeStamp you will need to create a SQL Query and return it to the application that you are using to show on the Client Machine.

you can try DateTime.UtcNow as well or

Look at some of these examples

```
The following examples use the six SQL Server system functions that return current date and time to return the date, time or both. The values are returned in series; therefore, their fractional seconds might be different.
A. Getting the current system date and time

SELECT 'SYSDATETIME()      ', SYSDATETIME();
SELECT 'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()', SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();
SELECT 'SYSUTCDATETIME()   ', SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT 'GETDATE()          ', GETDATE();
SELECT 'GETUTCDATE()       ', GETUTCDATE();
/* Returned:
SYSDATETIME()            2007-05-03 18:34:11.9351421
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()      2007-05-03 18:34:11.9351421 -07:00
SYSUTCDATETIME()         2007-05-04 01:34:11.9351421
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP        2007-05-03 18:34:11.933
GETDATE()                2007-05-03 18:34:11.933
GETUTCDATE()             2007-05-04 01:34:11.933
*/

B. Getting the current system date

SELECT 'SYSDATETIME()      ', CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME());
SELECT 'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()', CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());
SELECT 'SYSUTCDATETIME()   ', CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME());
SELECT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ', CONVERT (date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
SELECT 'GETDATE()          ', CONVERT (date, GETDATE());
SELECT 'GETUTCDATE()       ', CONVERT (date, GETUTCDATE());

/* Returned: 
SYSDATETIME()            2007-05-03
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()      2007-05-03
SYSUTCDATETIME()         2007-05-04
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP        2007-05-03
GETDATE()                2007-05-03
GETUTCDATE()             2007-05-04
*/

C. Getting the current system time

SELECT 'SYSDATETIME()      ', CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME());
SELECT 'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()', CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());
SELECT 'SYSUTCDATETIME()   ', CONVERT (time, SYSUTCDATETIME());
SELECT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ', CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
SELECT 'GETDATE()          ', CONVERT (time, GETDATE());
SELECT 'GETUTCDATE()       ', CONVERT (time, GETUTCDATE());
/* Returned
SYSDATETIME()            18:25:01.6958841
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()      18:25:01.6958841
SYSUTCDATETIME()         01:25:01.6958841
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP        18:25:01.6930000
GETDATE()                18:25:01.6930000
GETUTCDATE()             01:25:01.6930000
*/
```